# Is it possible to replace stdin file with any other file?

Tags: node.js, stdin, nohup

I have a nodejs server which will be started using nohup. So basically it will not have stdin.

I have created daemon for my nodejs server which does all start stop restart status functions.

But I dont want to stop the nodejs server immediately. I want to stop it after certain tasks. So I have to send command to the server's stdin. So that shutdown will be controlled by the server itself. Yes I can do that by creating a API. But its my last option.

Yes my server takes input from stdin and its working well. But using nohup I will not have stdin therefore no way to enter command in that case.

So my question is, if there is a way so that I can change the stdin to other file and my server will take input from it in the same way it does in case of stdin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in Linux or Mac you can send signals to your server process. In Windows you can too but I don't know the command.

For example if you want to reload your server you can do

`kill -s SIGUSR2 processId`

And in your server

```
process.on('SIGUSR2', function() {
    console.log('Got SIGUSR2, reloading server...');
});
```

Comment: As per the docs of nodejs I didnt find if nodejs listens to SIGUSR2. I will try it definitely. Thank you. Can you tell me what are the other signals which are not reserved but nodejs listens them..??

Comment: It does, I use it in one of my node apps. You can get a list of signals if you enter `kill -l` in the command line. `SIGUSR2` is common for reloading apps.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it. I will listen the SIGUSR2 signal then will do some jobs, which will take around 3-5min and then will call process.exit()